# How count Arabic numerals in a string containing utf8 character with PHP?

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
 function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
       $ret = array();
       $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
       for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
           $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
       }
       return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

When I execute like this:

```
$arr = str_split_unicode('你好，我将于2014年11月11日变成霸王龙，这非常的好看呢！一二三四五六七八九！', 21);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 你好，我将于2014年11月11日变成霸王
    [1] => 龙，这非常的好看呢！一二三四五六七八九！
)
```

This is not what I want. Because the Arabic number is count as 1 for 1, I hope to count 2 Arabic number as 1, how could I achieve this?

Comment: If this is for achieving a uniform block layout, this is misguided anyway. It ultimately depends on the font that's used to render the numbers; even if you use 2 numbers for every 1 Hanzi character, there's still no guarantee that they will line up nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here and will guess that you're actually trying to achieve a uniform block layout in which all characters line up in columns. For this purpose, you should rather use *full width numerals* ("zen-kaku") instead of trying to align them with 2-for-1:

```
echo mb_convert_kana('你好，我将于2014年11月11日变成霸王龙...', 'AS', 'UTF-8');
```

http://php.net/mb_convert_kana

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted the number of numbers in the string
Could this be the answer?

```
$str = '你好，我将于2014年11月11日变成霸王龙，这非常的好看呢！一二三四五六七八九！';
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $str, $output_array);
echo count($output_array[0]); //number of digits in a string. in this case 3
```